# Regression with SARIMA errors

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, stan

After an SARIMA transformation, is $\epsilon_t$ equal to the difference in observed original $y_t$ from its estimate or the equivalent quantity for *transformed* $y_t$, $y'_t$?

The motivation: I am trying to build a STAN model (called from R) and want to move from existing frequentist SARIMAX models to a broader state-space perspective. First, though, I want to reproduce the model and I want to code it manually so that I understand the guts. This leads me to my question:

Say that I have an $ARIMA(0, 1, 1)(0, 1, 1)_{52}$ model with regression coefficients (holidays, traffic on a given day, etc...). I know that I need to take seasonal and first differences for all covariates, leading to

$y'_t = \beta X'_t + \eta_t$,
where

$(1-B)(1-B^{52})\eta_t =  (1-\phi B)(1-\phi_{52} B_{52})\epsilon_t$

Perhaps naively, I plan to forecast using $\epsilon_t = y_{actual,t} - \hat{y_t}$. Should I use my *original* $y_t$ or my transformed $y'_t$? Does $\epsilon_t = y_{actual,t} - \hat{y_t}$ or $y'_{actual,t} - \hat{y'_t}$?

This question may just be clarification, but I've consulted Hyndman's ARIMAX blog post ([here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)), his [textbook chapter](https://otexts.com/fpp3/regarima.html) on regression with ARIMA errors,  his [slides](https://robjhyndman.com/talks/RevolutionR/11-Dynamic-Regression.pdf), the STAN manual [ARMA section](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_26/stan-users-guide/autoregressive-moving-average-models.html), and [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129901/sarima-model-equation) [helpful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425187/build-sarima-model-equation-with-exogenous-variable-or-regressors) [questions][7].